# Как на архитектуре BLoC сделать вебсокет с локальной sqlite базой данных

Tags: flutter, dart

Я реализую мессенджер.
Через Bloc реализовал авторизацию пользователя, после авторизации мне необходимо создать сокет соединение и с разных виджетов UI передавать запросы на сокет.
Плюс я должен класть данные пришедшие на сокет в локальную базу данных для дальнейшего отображения списка контактов и чата с пользователем.

На главной странице после авторизации я Созал МультиблокПровайдер

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider<WebSocketBloc>(
              create: (context) => WebSocketBloc(
                  webSocketRepo:
                      RepositoryProvider.of<WebSocketRepository>(context)),
            ),
            BlocProvider<DbBloc>(
              create: (context) => DbBloc(
                  dbRepo: RepositoryProvider.of<DBRepository>(context)),
            ),
          ],
          child: _transitionSwitcher(),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: pageIndex,
          onTap: (value) {
            setState(() {
              pageIndex = value;
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.messenger), label: "Chats"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.people), label: "People"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.call), label: "Calls"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: httpGetLogoImage(
                  SharedObjects.prefs!
                      .getString(Constants.sessionProfilePictureUrl),
                  5),
              label: "Profile",
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Создал Вебсокет блок и блок локального хранения данных.
Но мне непонятно

1. когда и в какой части кода инициализировать соединение с вебсокетом.
2. Как полученные события из вебсокета передать в блок локальной бд чтобы он эти данные положил.
3. Как после того как данные положились в локальную базу данных обновить блок контактов.

То есть все event создаются не UI а событием авторизации, когда пользователь успешно авторизировался идет запрос к вебсокету на запрос списка контактов. Слушатель стрима вебсокета принимает данные и кладет их в локальную базу данных, и после того как данные были добавлены в бд необходимо отобразить их на UI списка контактов.

Я возможно не совсем верно описал но надеюсь суть была понятна. Я новичок в dart.

Comment: То что вы пытаетесь сделать, должно делаться не на уровне Bloc, а на уровне даты (Repository <- Datasource). У вас есть 2 Datasource: Один для WebSocket, другой для DB. Repository принимает в себя их и использует их. На выходе у вас один Repository, который имеет данные как из DB так и из WebSocket, по условию нужному вам.

[Вот вам не самый лучший пример который поможет понять как это правильно организовать.](https://github.com/ResoCoder/flutter-tdd-clean-architecture-course/tree/master/lib/features/number_trivia/data)

Comment: https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html